# Where to find informations for projective planes over algebraic closed fields like $\bar{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, projective-space

The title really says it all:

*where can I find some informations about projective planes over algebraically closed fields like $\mathbb{P}^2_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}$*?

Here $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ stands for the algebraic closure of the field of rational numbers. I mean, for $\mathbb{C}$ there are well known references, but here for this particular case above I can't find something useful.

I'm interested in particular in the study of algebraic curves in these spaces.

Comment: Lots of algebraic geometry books work over an arbitrary field $k$. Then you can just set $k=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$. Hartshorne for example.

Comment: The LMFDB might have something, though I have no idea where to look for it.

Comment: I am not sure you will find something specifically on $\overline{\Bbb Q}$. The usual hypothesis on the field are algebraically closed and of characteristic zero, so as ziggurism the usual textbook e.g Hartshorne should apply. 

This said, related is the famous Belyi's theorem : let $X$ be a complex projective curve, then $X$ is defined over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ if and only if there is a morphism $f : X \to \Bbb P^1$ ramified only at $0,1$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you all. I found quite a lot of informations on Hartshorne, so thank you again @ziggurism.